# Placing <span> element and fontawesome icon in same line

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a problem placing elements in one line.

```
<div class="container">
  <ul id="suggestion_list"> 
    <li class="mp_search_suggest_element">
        <span >
            <b>some bold text</b> here 
            <i class="fa fa-bed fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="mp_search_suggest_element">
        <span >
            <b>some bold text</b> some long text here
            <i class="fa fa-bed fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I load the ul dynamically via ajax in the container div.
I'd like to have the text aligned to the left, the icon to the right, in one line. So the line stretches the container div to fit in and never displays the text or the icon in two lines.

The css:

```
.container {
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   width: auto;
   min-width: 350px;
   max-width: 600px;
   padding: 10px 0;
 }

 ul{
   list-style-type: none;
 }

 li{
   width: 100%;
   white-space: nowrap ;
 }
```

So this is what I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this with flexbox if you like. make the li a flexbox container.

see example:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 350px;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #333;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #eee;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
li span:nth-child(2){
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css ">
<div class="container">
  <ul id="suggestion_list">
    <li class="mp_search_suggest_element">
      <span><b>some bold text</b> text here</span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-bed fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

    </li>
    <li class="mp_search_suggest_element">
      <span><b>some bold text</b> some long text here</span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-bed fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-wrap: nowrap; to not go on 2 lines :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to remove the **fa-fw** class because it add a **text-align: center;** to the **icon**. Then, it is necessary that you separate the **texts** and the **icon**, so that the positioning of these is easier.

I made an exemple to show you how I did it: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7t9dk2eo/5/).

I changed the HTML structure of you're **li**:

```
<li class="mp_search_suggest_element">
  <span><b>some bold text</b> here</span><i class="fa fa-bed fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</li>
```

I also changed the CSS of you're **li** and added some for the **texts** and the **icon**:

```
li {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
 }
```

I hope it solve you're problem.
**UPDATE: Added the calc CSS (See my comment).**

Comment: @ Frank Nole Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! I edited the https://jsfiddle.net/7t9dk2eo/7/ to show my problem. I need the icon to the right.

Comment: I updated the same JSFiddle. You're CSS is correct but for one thing. When you use the calc() function, you have to put space between the numbers and the operator.

    span {
      width: calc(100% - 30px);
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float:right;` to make it aligned right with `transform: translateY(-100%) !important;`

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 350px;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100%-30px);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid green;
  float: right;
  transform: translateY(-100%) !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <ul id="suggestion_list">
    <li class="mp_search_suggest_element">
      <span><b>some bold text</b> hedfreaf asf sasdasdasf asdf f adsf asdf sdf sdf</span><i class="fa fa-bed" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="mp_search_suggest_element">
      <span><b>some bold text</b> here</span><i class="fa fa-bed" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If I float to right, the icon is displayed in a second line. I need the icon in the same line at the right.

Comment: If I run the code snippet, the icons are one line below the span .

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for. There are some classes that font awesome gives you that you can add to your different list tags to make it inline.

https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/icons-in-a-list

Comment: Link only answers are considered **very low quality** because it does not directly answer the question and solve the problem. Links are usually used as a reference to the answer that is given